# didBeginContact() called without contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skphysicsbody

I have a game that is ready to publish, but my fiancé who is still on iOS 8.1 had this issue. It's fine with iOS 9 but I recreated the problem on the simulator with iOS 8.1.

When I click start game and the scene is loaded, enemies begin to appear at the edges of the screen. They use actions to push them to the other edge of the screen and then they are removed from their parent. Only, didBeginContact() is called as soon as they are added to the screen.

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
    static let None     : UInt32 = 0
    static let All      : UInt32 = UInt32.max
    static let fishy    : UInt32 = 0b1       // 1
    static let enemy    : UInt32 = 0b10      // 2
    static let powerup    : UInt32 = 0b11      // 3
}
```

Good guy (fishy) set up and movement)

```
fishy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:fishy.texture!, size:fishy.size)
    fishy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    fishy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.fishy
    fishy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy
    fishy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    fishy.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

Enemy set up and movement

```
enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:enemy.texture!, size:enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true // 2
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy // 3
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.fishy // 4
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 5

self.addChild(enemy)
    let action1 = SKAction.rotateToAngle(angle, duration: 0.0, shortestUnitArc: true)
    let action = SKAction.moveTo(finishPos,duration:Double(random(min: 5,max: 13)))
    let action2 = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action1,action,action2])
enemy.runAction(sequence)
```

This is called for most of the enemy nodes that are added, but not all. I only want it called when they contact, but it is running at their creation. (It calls even when the path of the enemy is not in contact with the fishy)

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var enemyContact: SKPhysicsBody
    var fishyContact: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        fishyContact = contact.bodyA
        enemyContact = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        fishyContact = contact.bodyB
        enemyContact = contact.bodyA
    }
    if ((enemyContact.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.enemy != 0) && (fishyContact.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.fishy != 0)) {
        if (enemyContact.node != nil && fishyContact.node != nil) {
                projectileDidCollide(fishyContact.node as! SKSpriteNode, badGuy:enemyContact.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this doesn't occur in iOS 9.0 and above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `powerup` category should be 0b100 (4) not 0b11 (3). Try setting `view.showsPhysics = true` to see the shapes/sizes of the bodies in your scene.

Comment: on creation, are you sure the enemy is not spawning on top of player?

Comment: Why should it be 4 instead of 3?
I am sure, I had the console show both positions and they were on opposite sides of the view

Comment: Categories should be incremented in doubles: 1-2-4-8-16

Comment: If you set node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = `powerup` (0b11), node will collide with `fishy` (0b01), `enemy` (0b10), and `powerup`.

Comment: This was never solved, I ended up only allowing ios9 and above download it.

Comment: Did you ever correct the category bitmask for powerup?